# Cassandra paging in ordered by time transactions table

Tags: sorting, cassandra, transactions

I have the following table/column family Cassandra to store transactions ordered by time (descendant), which each transaction belongs to an account:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    transaction_id uuid,
    description text,
    account_id uuid,
    category text,
    sub_category text,
    date timestamp,
    amount bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (account_id, date, transaction_id, amount)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date DESC);
```

I would like to have paging in transactions, fetching groups of 25 transactions ordered by date as well, for a specific account.

Is that possible with this definition or i need other additional CF to help this feature? What you would suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure why you have amount in your PK but that shouldn't matter for now.

You can for a given account fetch results 25 at a time ordered by date. The Datastax Native driver will let you do this via the paging options.

```
//Expected inputs account_id and if not the first page a state 
//string from the last page of data

Select query = select().from('keyspace', 'transactions')
.where(eq('account_id', account_id))
.orderBy(desc('date'))

if (state) {
    query.setPagingState(PagingState.fromString(state))
}

query.setFetchSize(25)

ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(query)    

String newState = resultSet.getExecutionInfo().pagingState?.toString()

//This will get you just the 25 rows you requested first
resultSet.getAvailableWithoutFetching()

//When sending data back to the page you will need to make sure you also 
//send back the paging state so it can help you go to the next 25.
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm using cqerl for erlang, not sure if can follow the same approach. The amount probably is a mistake when i design the table some time ago.

Comment: So the paging State is part of the cql version that is supported by cqerl, I don't know if they expose that information but if not you should be able to add it.

Comment: I just don't know the syntax for erlang sorry.

Comment: @lealoureiro Have you been able to make any progress on this?

Comment: I found out that cqerl has paging mechanism as well, as you suggested, but i wanna do paging in front device as well, and i believe i cannot keep the state to ask for more pages, if the new request is processed by another erlang process/client.

Comment: Can you point to the paging doc for the Erlang client I'll see if I can figure out the stateless bit.